# WAF makes sense?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-waf

I'm running a company web application in aws. This web app is behind a cognito+External Identity provider with saml for only allowing company employees to reach the app (then they log in with local credentials to the app, as it is not possible to use saml).
In this context, does it make sense to put a WAF? A potential attacker could not launch attacks if he is not authenticated.
Thanks

Farid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A potential attacker could not launch attacks if he is not authenticated.

That's a very strong assumption. Most of incidents happen using stolen credentials, bad actors (malicious users) or an application bug

As well your application is not behind the Cognito, but both need to accesible to the clients or public internet directly.

> does it make sense to put a WAF?

WAF protects partly against DDoS  (filtering specific IP addresses or regions) and some other attack types (sql injection,..).

Every additional component is a tradeoff decision with complexity, usability and price. If it's worth - it is a decision if the threats or incident impacts are worth the price and effort to learn and manage the waf (baseline setup provides only baseline protection, for the best results you have to put the best effort to learn and manage the waf rules)

Maybe it's not an answer you are looking for and the question is more suited for  https://security.stackexchange.com/    , but it's your decision

Comment: Thanks for that! You're correct about the stolen credentials. I will also take your suggestion and post this question also in https://security.stackexchange.com/ to get even information

Answer (score 0):

WAF will assist you with protecting your app from various different kinds of exploits on the web. Regardless of the AWS Cognito authentication which you have described, there are many, many vulnerabilities you might still be open to, DDOS attacks being one simple example.

If your web server is publicly accessible from a network perspective (unrelated to whether someone can login or not) then it still might make sense to use WAF.

Answer (score 0):

Even an authenticated users may try to run an attack.

So WAF is of use even if you're using an IdP.